# Something to print some monitoring stuff in a shell screen

Tags: linux, monitoring, shell

I think I saw it before somewhere, but I can't remember where and what it's name was...

Well, basically I'm seaching for a soft that can put some monitoring values at the top (or th bottom) of the shell screen.

Something like conky but for systems without an X server / window manager.

Does anyone got what I mean ? :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to do something like this, I typically turn to GNU Screen, running in split-screen mode. You can configure where the split happens in the terminal window, so if your monitoring output only needs 3 lines, then you can configure the split that way, giving the rest of the terminal window to your interactive session.

Additionally, by using Screen, you gain all of the other ancillary benefits that screen provides: session detach/attach, screen sharing, multiple bash sessions in one terminal window, etc.

Comment: Never thought of using screen this way, will have a look, thx ;)

Comment: Good luck! Also, keep in mind that you can configure your .screenrc to set up the split and launch your monitoring script in the appropriate window automatically.